# Problem with updating html site dynamically with python / flask + ajax

Tags: python, html, ajax, flask

I have a python/flask app file with a file dropzone
I start a function from another py file once a file has been uploaded.
Now I need to print a string when the file is uploaded on the website
This is the part of the app file:

```
logger = None

@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])

def upload():
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files.get('file')
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADED_PATH'],f.filename))
        es.main() 
        global logger
        logger = "something here"
    return render_template('index.html', logger=logger)
```

This is the html file:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){
  window.setInterval(funtion(),{
  loadNewLogger() 
}, 100)

function loadNewLogger(){

  $.ajax({
    url:"/",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "text",
    success: function(data){
      $(update_logger).replaceWith(data)
    }
  });
}
});


</script>
<body>
    <div style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0);text-align:center"> 
    NAME </div>
  
  {{ dropzone.create(action='upload') }}
  {{ dropzone.load_js() }}
  {{ dropzone.config() }}
  

  <div id="update_logger">
    {{ logger }}
  </div>
```

The problem is that nothing happens. The html site shows "None", when it should print "something here" after uploading a file.
Whats wrong with that code?

Comment: Did you check what does `data` has ?

Comment: no, how can I check it?

Comment: if you need a quick answer to that, then use console.log(data) or try to set a breakpoint in your browser debugger. e.g. for chome: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that by default your route accepts a `GET` request. So whenever you make a get, it directly runs `return render_template('index.html', logger=logger)`; but you see this time it does not have access to the line `logger = "something here"`. That means that line never gets executed when there is a `GET` request, hence the value of `logger` stays `None`.
What you could do is to add a `return logger`

```
logger = None

@app.route('/',methods=['POST','GET'])

def upload():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files.get('file')
        f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOADED_PATH'],f.filename))
        es.main() 
        global logger
        logger = "something here"
        return logger

    return render_template('index.html', logger=logger)
```

Make sure you import `url_for()` -- `from flask import url_for`

Comment: Nothing happens with your solution. None stays None

Comment: You can return logger then. After `logger = "Something here"` do `return logger` since you ajax takes it and updates the div with it. Let me know if it works; I have updated the "solution" as well.

Comment: I works now when I reload the page, but not after dropping the files